# scikit learn mean shift clustering in one-dimensional array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

how can I run a mean shift clustering on a 1D array?
Here there is my dataframe:
    `>>>df
        INFO         FREQ
     R2   31    0.2468213
     R5   27  0.003670532
     UR   25   0.00337465`

I need to apply the clustering on the "INFO" column.
Whit the kmeans I solved this problem using the reshape(-1,1) command:
`kmeans.fit(df["INFO"].values.reshape(-1,1))` , but with the mean shift clustering I get this error:
`meanshift.fit(df["INFO"].values.reshape(-1,1))` output: `ValueError: Invalid shape in axis 1: 0.`

Comment: Is your data really 3 elements long?

Comment: MeanShift with a random 1D vector of length > 3 works perfectly fine. So the question is, why would you like to apply kmeans, meanshift or any other kind of clustering to a 3 element vector? Do you apply it just because is *cool*? Because it has no mathematical meaning whatsoever.

Comment: Its really easy to cluster a 3 element array. Each one of them is a cluster. No algorithms needed! yay!

Comment: my full dataset is about 4500000 rows and it's part of a automatic process where it is not possible to fit the K (for the K-means)

Answer (score 2):

It does not make *sense* to run mean-shift on one-dimensional data.

Do regular **kernel density estimation** instead. Locate the minima, and split the data set there.

Mean shift is for data that is too complex for proper KDE.

One dimensional data *never* is.